# Display year,quarter,month and day Charts based on the selected Date

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

There are four line charts for Year,Quarter,Month,Day in my power bi report. the requirement is to pick a date from the date picker and based on the selected date I need to display graphs accordingly(selected date and 3 values back). E.g. if user select 1.1.2018 from date picker, I need to display graphs with year,quarter,month,day belong to 1.1.2018 and 3 more values(years,quarters,months,days) back.

I add visual level filters for each line chart and filter top 4 values.but it's work for year chart only. any ideas? 
[Dashboard_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwfAo.jpg)
[Dashboard_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zJHG.jpg)

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jC7R5.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Dasaru try to create separate columns for year, quarter, month & date and use that as Axis in each chart

```
FYYear = Sheet1[Period].[Year]
FYQuarter = Sheet1[Period].[Year]&" "&Sheet1[Period].[Quarter]
```

Apply the same solution for Month and Date.